# Unit testing class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm doing unit testing with a class library and I'm stuck on how to test the method that need to test scenarios like check if a password with less than 8 characters cannot be accepted, check if a password with 8 or more characters can be accepted and check if a password with space in the front cannot be accepted.

The code below is from the class library.

```
public class PasswordChecker
{
    public bool CheckPassword(string pwd)
{
    if (pwd.Length >= 8 && !pwd.StartsWith(""))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

The code below is from the testing project.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using 12kiajunPA03;

namespace PasswordCheckerTest
{
[TestClass]
public class PasswordCheckerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Checkpassword()
    {
        string pwd = "1234qa1";

        Checkpassword password = new Checkpassword("John", pwd);

        try
        {

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it would look something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using 12kiajunPA03;

namespace PasswordCheckerTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PasswordCheckerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Checkpassword8CharsLong()
        {
            string validPassword = "12345678";
            string invalidPassword = "abc";

            PasswordChecker checker = new PasswordChecker();

            Assert.IsTrue(checker.CheckPassword(validPassword));
            Assert.IsFalse(checker.CheckPassword(invalidPassword));
        }
    }
}
```

Using the same idea, you could write additional tests that check for other criteria that the passwords must meet.

Comment: You'll either want to use test cases or more than one test. If the first check fails the second is never run in your test which can hide bugs.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not familiar with this testing framework specifically, but in my experience with `Assert` in other frameworks, tests continue even if previous ones fail.

Comment: I've not seen a framework do that though I could be wrong with MSTest, I use XUnit for testing.